# Change order of axis in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I havea  numpy array with shape:

```
(360L, 720L, 2L)
```

How do I change it to:

```
(2L, 360L, 720L)
```

Comment: [numpy.transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Comment: thanks @steve, that gives : (2L, 720L, 360L), I want (2L, 360L, 720L)

Comment: It's a link. I think that would be `numpy.transpose(x,(2,0,1))`

Comment: `array[0] = oldArray[3]` and `array[1] = oldArray[0]`. The last one you can figure out yourself.

Comment: thanks @steve, that works